# Как можно упростить данную функцию на Python?

Tags: python

Функция проверяет больше ли баланс клиента, чем стоимость ценной бумаги, помноженной на количество этих бумаг и, если на балансе достаточно средств, то уменьшает баланс на эту сумму и увеличивает количество ценных бумаг. Подскажите, как можно упростить эту функцию?

```
def buy_securities(self, stock, count):
    if self._cash > stock.value * count:
        self._cash -= stock.value * count
        self._stocks[stock] += count
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем это? Функция из 3-х строк, все хорошо читается и понятно, что делается.

Comment: Я бы даже усложнил - ``>=`` вместо ``>``.

Comment: Упрощать особо нечего, разве только `stock.value * count` присвоить переменной, поскольку используется дважды. А вот знак `>` точно нужно поменять на `>=`

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, какие есть возможности, чтобы еще более лаконично написать эту функцию? Тернарный оператор тут не подойдет, упростить выражение тоже не получается. Возможно все-таки можно каким-то образом сделать код короче и лаконичнее?

Comment: Код и так достаточно короткий и лаконичный

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с вышеупомянутыми комментариями, что ваша функция и так проста и лаконична, но предлагаю такой вариант реализации:

```py
def buy_securities(self, stock, count):
    cost = stock.value * count
    if self._cash > cost:
        self._cash -= cost
        self._stocks[stock] += count
```

Comment: Ваш код так же не позволяет купить акции на все деньги, как и начальный :)